# System.out.printIn cannot find symbol

Tags: java

Whenever I try to compile this Java program in the command prompt I get an error about `System.out.printIn` saying that javac cannot find symbol. System.out.print works just fine but System.out.printIn refuses to cooperate. I've posted the program and the compiler message below. Thanks for the help.

```
    public class BeerSong {
public static void main (String[] args) {
int beerNum = 99;
String word = "bottles";

while (beerNum > 0) {

  if (beerNum == 1) {
    word = "bottle"; //singular, ONE bottle
}

System.out.printIn(beerNum + " " + word + "of beer on the wall");
System.out.printIn(beerNum + " " + word + "of beer.");
System.out.printIn("Take one down.");
System.out.printIn("Pass it around.");
beerNum = beerNum - 1;

if (beerNum > 0) {
    System.out.printIn(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
}   else {
    System.out.printIn("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
} //end else
} //end while loop
} //end main method
} //end class
```

---

```
C:\Users\Jesse\Desktop>javac BeerSong.java
BeerSong.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method printIn(java.lang.String)
location: class java.io.PrintStream
    System.out.printIn(beerNum + " " + word + "of beer on the wall");
              ^
BeerSong.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method printIn(java.lang.String)
location: class java.io.PrintStream
    System.out.printIn(beerNum + " " + word + "of beer.");
              ^
BeerSong.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method printIn(java.lang.String)
location: class java.io.PrintStream
    System.out.printIn("Take one down.");
              ^
BeerSong.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method printIn(java.lang.String)
location: class java.io.PrintStream
    System.out.printIn("Pass it around.");
              ^
BeerSong.java:19: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method printIn(java.lang.String)
location: class java.io.PrintStream
        System.out.printIn(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
                  ^
BeerSong.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method printIn(java.lang.String)
location: class java.io.PrintStream
            System.out.printIn("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
                      ^
6 errors
```

Comment: what is `printIn` it should be `println`

Comment: The real answer is that beer and Java don't go together :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is println with `l` (lower case `L`), not `I` (upper case `i`).

Comment: In addition: `ln` stands for `line` as in print line, not printIn => print ... input?! ;)

Comment: See I had a feeling it was something simple. Thanks so much. Thats what I get for using a blurry pdf Java guide.

Comment: wow this is stupid.. whatever happened to camelCase?

Comment: I believed in capital `I` also! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Typo:

`printIn` should be `println`

Answer (score 3):

it is `System.out.println` and NOT `System.out.printIn` (lower case L and not upper case i)

Comment: in his post it is letter I as in upper i :)

Answer (score 3):

It should be `System.out.println` not `System.out.printIn`.

Use some kind of IDE (like Eclipse or NetBeans) to make sure that you can use methos in current context.

The problem here is copying the same line. Try avoiding copy/pase.